# How to fix error: Computed value too large, when performing supervised classification using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to run a supervised object-based image analysis on a Sentinel 2 image using a 13 class shapefile to train the classifier, but I am having trouble running the classification part of it and get the error: computed value to large.  I am using the following code (based on https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/classification)

```
    Map.addLayer(training, {color: 'red'}, 'training');

  // Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var trainedpolygons = image.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection: training,
  // Keep this list of properties from the polygons.
  properties: ['classvalue'],
  // Set the scale to get Sentinel pixels in the polygons.
  scale: 10
});

// Create an SVM classifier with custom parameters.
var classifier = ee.Classifier.svm({
  kernelType: 'RBF',
  gamma: 0.5,
  cost: 10
});

// Train the classifier.
var trained = classifier.train(trainedpolygons, 'classvalue');

 // Classify the image.
 var classified = image.classify(trained);

// Display the classification result and the input image.
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.5, gamma: 2});
Map.addLayer(classified,
            {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'green']});`
```

Full code can be found here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8f8a4ffeafd1e8c94869099583c53d4f

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Our short [tour] emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question and you seem to have several unmarked questions in this one.